# why servlet redirection is fast?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I want to know why redirection in a servlet is better than `JavaScript` redirection.

Also I wonder why `JavaScript` redirection is slow?

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but for reference: [tag:java] != [tag:javascript]. Retagged.

Comment: it kind of is relevant because servlets are usually implemented in java

Comment: I know java!=javascript :)

Comment: He was directing that at @Telthien who made a potentially invalid edit.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I didn't see Java in the question, and assumed it was a misunderstanding. Replacing the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most server-side redirection is implemented with a `Location: http://www.example.com` [HTTP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) (and a 302 code). When the browser reads this in the headers, it (should) immediately stop what it's doing and start fetching that page.

When it's implemented in JavaScript, typically (depending on how you implement it) the entire page has to load (or at least download) before the JavaScript executes to start redirection.

Answer (score 3):

the redirect (301 or 302 status) sent from the servlet is a header only, so the browser doesnt have to load anything else or parse any html or javascript